# Make 'read' work when not focused on terminal

Tags: shell-script, terminal, xdotool

I have the following script which spams a button in a program when the V button is pressed

```
#!/bin/bash
winid=$(xdotool search "application name here" | head -n1)
while true; do
read -rsn1 input
if [ "$input" = "v" ]; then
    xdotool keydown --window $winid "button"
    xdotool keyup --window $winid "button"
fi
done
```

However, this only works when the the terminal is focused, is there any way to make it listen to all key presses?

Comment: Could you please tell us what your ultimate goal is? Whatever you're trying to do (and how you're trying to do) is really weird to me.

Comment: I would use it for a number of programs. Mostly games though, for example mGBA, to spam through pressing A. (It's quite tiring, actually)

Comment: Sorry, I totally don't get it. Care to explain the entire story from the beginning to the end, please?

Comment: I play pokemon on a GBA emulator. This lets me speed up the game, however I still need to press "X" as fast as possible to actually do anything. I would like a script that presses X as fast as possible for me (but only when I am holding the B button down).

Comment: OK I see :) One possibility that occurs to me right now is to use `xbindkeys` or something similar instead of a shell script and its "read" statement – as it was already recommended to you by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the *root* user:

```
cat /dev/input/$(grep -E  'Handlers|EV=' /proc/bus/input/devices | \
                 grep -B1 'EV=120013' |  grep -Eo 'event[0-9]+') | \
while read -rsn1 foo ; do echo "$foo" ; done | nl
```

Output (until *Ctrl-C*):

```
     1  ԥ
     2  �W
     3  ^
     4  
     5
```

The code reads from whichever */dev/input/event** file currently corresponds to the keyboard.  Echos each keypress on separate lines, then numbers each line -- keypresses accumulate quickly, so the line numbers help show the routine is working.

Try opening a text editor in a small foreground window, enter some text in the editor, and notice the numbers scroll by on the background terminal.

---

The `grep` code above borrowed from *JacobP*'s answer here:
[Linux keyboard event capturing /dev/inputX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775461/linux-keyboard-event-capturing-dev-inputx/22568258#22568258)

Comment: okay thx, but is there any way to actually detect if I pressed a certain button and then execute a command?

Comment: @MightyAlex200 Yes, use a tool designed for this purpose, such as xbindkeys. Your script is not at all useful for this.